# how to check if file is php?

Tags: php, regex

i want to check if a file has the extensions .php. if it has i include it.

could someone help me with a regexp check?

thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usually you don't use a regular expression.

The following is a popular method instead:

```
$extension=pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 5):

[pathinfo](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php) is the easiest solution, but you can also use [fnmatch](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php)

```
if( fnmatch('*.php', $filename) ) { /* do something */ }
```

---

**EDIT:** Like @zombat points out in the comments, if you are after a *fast* solution, then the following is faster than using `pathinfo` and `fnmatch`:

```
if( substr($filename, -4) === '.php' ) { /* do something */ }
```

Keep in mind that `pathinfo`, unlike `fnmatch` and `substr` does a `basename` check on the path you provide, which makes it somewhat cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: Concerning speed, fnmatch will out perform pathinfo 2:1 when used for this purpose.

Comment: @zaf now that you mention it.. **no, it doesn't**. What made me think that?! LOL. But still, it's slower.

Comment: @Gordon you need a slap for that. I'll be scrutinizing all your answers and comments from now on. Watch it. ;)

Comment: @zaf yes, do so please, otherwise I'll keep spreading lies, unintentionally though, but still :) Best to remove the comment.

Comment: @Gordon & @webbiedave check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693428/pathinfo-vs-fnmatch

Comment: If all you're doing is checking for ".php" on the end, why would you ever use something that needed wildcard matching?  `if (substr($filename,-4) == '.php')` blows both these methods out of the water in terms of speed.

Comment: @zombat I gave fnmatch as an alternative to pathinfo because pathinfo was given already and because many people don't seem to know fnmatch exists. Didn't give it because it's faster. I wasn't even aware it is until @webbiedave pointed it out. Yes, substr is faster than both.

Answer (score 2):

```
/\.php$/
```

but extension mapping doesn't ensure the content is what you expect, just that a file is named a particular way.

Comment: Good point.  There are a lot of other file extensions that indicate PHP content: .module, .inc, .test, .install, etc.