# (Pathinfo vs fnmatch part 2) Speed benchmark reversed on Windows and Mac

Tags: php, cross-platform, benchmarking

On a previous question the pathinfo and fnmatch functions were benchmarked and the answers all came out **opposite** to my benchmark results.

You can read the different results with the benchmark code here:
[pathinfo vs fnmatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693428/pathinfo-vs-fnmatch)

I couldn't work it out until I ran the same code on a machine running vista. The results then matched the other users. My main machine is a mac.

So, my questions are:

- Why do we get these two different results?
- Could this apply to other functions?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it as there are hardly any mac production servers out there.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do we get these two different
>   results?

fnmatch should be mapped to the OS's underlying fnmatch command (Windows has no such command and was unavailable until PHP 5.3). Apple's implementation of the command must be less speedy.

> Could this apply to other functions?

You could check [glob()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) for speed issues as it also performs regex on filenames.

**Edit:** Glob does not regex. It, well, globs. (thanks to salathe)

Comment: Globbing is not *performing regex* at all.